# System.TypeInitializationException error on opening mysql connection

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I just recently started experiencing with ASP.net by using the MVC pattern.

What im trying to do is create a login form with users from a Local phpmyadmin database, now my problem is that when im trying to open the MySqlConnection `_mscCon.Open();` it gives me an error:

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception.'
>
> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

Now im not understanding what this error means and how i am able to fix it, i tried changing the port of my WAMPSERVER and the port of my ASP.NET Localhost and this doesnt seem to work.

```
private MySqlConnection _mscCon = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=asptest;Uid=root;Pwd=;");

        public bool CheckCredentials(string username, string password)
        {

            _mscCon.Open();

            if (_mscCon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                MySqlCommand mscCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM users WHERE Username = " + username + " AND Password = " + password + ";", _mscCon);

                using (MySqlDataReader reader = mscCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Does anyone know what i might be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue may be resolved if you install MySQL Connector/NET (choose your version)

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/8.0.html